# Q: Whats wrong with this java code?

Tags: java, syntax

```
package firstproject;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class walkthrough {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String a = in.nextLine();       
        System.out.println("Welcome home!");
        System.out.println("Would you like to go in?");
        String door = a;
        if(a.equals(door));
        System.out.println("Your are now in the house what now?");
    }        
}
```

Comment: Hint: Check your `if` statement.

Comment: Semicolon after the `if()`. Voting to close as a simple typographical error.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Questions which consist solely of code are rarely *good* questions. Please take a bit of time to make your question clear - explaining what you're seeing, what you've tried to do to fix it, and what's still wrong. Additionally, take some time to make sure that your post is formatted so that it's easy to read... for example, the code in your original question is *not* well formatted. (Use tabs instead of spaces, and indent appropriately.) Please read http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints for more details of how to write a really good question.

Comment: An interview/exam question it seems. Multiple errors. Something for clear-voyants.

Comment: @JonSkeet I remember there's something written about this in the JLS but cannot find it, can you please help?

Comment: @MarounMaroun: About what? (I can't tell whether this is a joke around vague questions, or something specific you're genuinely asking about...)

Comment: @JonSkeet About `if(something);` is equivalent to `if(something) { }`... I remember I saw it once..

Comment: @MarounMaroun: I don't remember seeing anything explicitly about it...

Comment: @JonSkeet My mistake, I was referring [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.6).

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
if(a.equals(door));
    System.out.println("Your are now in the house what now?");
```

is:

```
if(a.equals(door)) { }
System.out.println("Your are now in the house what now?");
```

The print statement will be executed regardless of the value of the expression in the `if` condition.

Remove the redundant `;` after the `if` condition.

Also please follow the conventions and rename your class to begin with a capital letter.

Answer (score 0):

Semicolon after if statement. Change ; in {

Answer (score 0):

```
if(a.equals(door)); // semicolon - statement
        System.out.println("Your are now in the house what now?");
```

Which means `System.out.println("Your are now in the house what now?");` is executed irrespective of `if` statement.

Answer (score -1):

Class names should start with a capital letter in Java: `walkthrough` -> `Walkthrough`

Comment: Yes, but that's a convention not a compulsory thing, I mean compiler won't complain if you don't start it with capital letter. That's not the problem with above code.

Comment: User was asking what's wrong with his code. Inproper naming of classes certainly is, no matter whether its just a convention or not.